# html/css displaying content inline

Tags: html, css

I have made a basic grid for my first website that I am coding from scratch. However, I'm having issues with the content as it keeps overflowing onto the row below.

I've tried a few different things but can't get it to work. If I make the image smaller they will display inline, but I would like to have it all within one row.

See the image below - I have 3 sections of content and want them to display on one row.

[image]

Thanks for any answers!

```css
.section {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  GRID OF SIX  */
.span_6_of_6 {
 width: 100%;
}

.span_5_of_6 {
   width: 83.06%;
}

.span_4_of_6 {
   width: 66.13%;
}

.span_3_of_6 {
   width: 49.2%;
}

.span_2_of_6 {
   width: 32.26%;
}

.span_1_of_6 {
   width: 15.33%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
 .span_1_of_6, .span_2_of_6, .span_3_of_6, .span_4_of_6, .span_5_of_6, .span_6_of_6 { width: 100%; }
}

#content1 { 
 margin-left: 50px;
 margin-top: 50px; 
 margin-right: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 50px
 padding-right: 50px; 
 }

 #box1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 8%;
  margin-bottom: 8%; 
  margin-left: 2%
  margin-right: 2%; 
  padding-left: 15px; 
  padding-right: 15px;


  }
```

```html
<div class="section group">


  <div class="col span_2_of_6" id="box1"> 
   <h3>Paid Social</h3>
   <p>We do paid social work for a variety of clients. This is carried out on platforms including Facebook, Twitter, Youtube and LinkedIn. We can use our extensive knowledge of paid social to target audiences across multiple devices.</p> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="col span_2_of_6" id="box1"> 
  <h3>Paid Search</h3>
  <p>We do paid search work for a variey of clients. Using this channel has proven successful for all our of our clients and is key to generate new leads for a business.</p>
  </div>

   <div class="col span_2_of_6" id="box1"> 
   <h3>Analytics</h3>
   <p>We do analytics work for a variety of clients. Analytics is incredibly important when it comes to understanding our paid media efforts and the kinds of actions your audience takes once it has been acquired through these channels.</p>
   </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Also, you have several elements with same id, you should convert `box1` to a class.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were careful with your columns and the margins adding up properly. I think the only thing that you are missing is that `width` does not include the padding or border of an element unless you use `box-sizing` in your css. Try adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to your `.col` class and your content will appear on one row.

```css
.section {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  GRID OF SIX  */
.span_6_of_6 {
 width: 100%;
}

.span_5_of_6 {
   width: 83.06%;
}

.span_4_of_6 {
   width: 66.13%;
}

.span_3_of_6 {
   width: 49.2%;
}

.span_2_of_6 {
   width: 32.26%;
}

.span_1_of_6 {
   width: 15.33%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
 .span_1_of_6, .span_2_of_6, .span_3_of_6, .span_4_of_6, .span_5_of_6, .span_6_of_6 { width: 100%; }
}

#content1 { 
 margin-left: 50px;
 margin-top: 50px; 
 margin-right: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 50px
 padding-right: 50px; 
 }

 #box1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 8%;
  margin-bottom: 8%; 
  margin-left: 2%
  margin-right: 2%; 
  padding-left: 15px; 
  padding-right: 15px;


  }
```

```html
<div class="section group">


  <div class="col span_2_of_6" id="box1"> 
   <h3>Paid Social</h3>
   <p>We do paid social work for a variety of clients. This is carried out on platforms including Facebook, Twitter, Youtube and LinkedIn. We can use our extensive knowledge of paid social to target audiences across multiple devices.</p> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="col span_2_of_6" id="box1"> 
  <h3>Paid Search</h3>
  <p>We do paid search work for a variey of clients. Using this channel has proven successful for all our of our clients and is key to generate new leads for a business.</p>
  </div>

   <div class="col span_2_of_6" id="box1"> 
   <h3>Analytics</h3>
   <p>We do analytics work for a variety of clients. Analytics is incredibly important when it comes to understanding our paid media efforts and the kinds of actions your audience takes once it has been acquired through these channels.</p>
   </div>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this code has been simplfied, but should accomplish what you are wanting...

```
<style>
.section {
clear: both;
margin: 0px auto;
width: 100%;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
display: block;
float:left;
margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0;}


.span_2_of_6 {
width: calc(29.3% - 30px);
position: relative;
float: left;
}


 #box1 {
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
margin: 8% 2%;
padding: 0% 15px;

  }

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="section group">


  <div class="col span_2_of_6" id="box1"> 
   <h3>Paid Social    </h3>
   <p>We do paid social work for a variety of clients. This is carried out on platforms including Facebook, Twitter, Youtube and LinkedIn. We can use our extensive knowledge of paid social to target audiences across multiple devices.    </p> 
  </div>

  <div class="col span_2_of_6" id="box1"> 
  <h3>Paid Search</h3>
  <p>We do paid search work for a variey of clients. Using this channel has proven successful for all our of our clients and is key to generate new leads for a business.</p>
  </div>

   <div class="col span_2_of_6" id="box1"> 
   <h3>Analytics</h3>
   <p>We do analytics work for a variety of clients. Analytics is incredibly important when it comes to understanding our paid media efforts and the kinds of actions your audience takes once it has been acquired through these channels.</p>
   </div>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

additionally, after fixing this issue you might want to have a look into [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (display:flex) which will help you solving layout issues aligning elements in one column (or row). Here's an excellent article

Another layout option: CSS Grid. [Still new though](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid).